# Were there any hints about this character’s true identity in Deep Space Nine?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

The episode [In Purgatory's Shadow](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/In_Purgatory%27s_Shadow_%28episode%29%5D%5B) reveals that:

> Julian Bashir had been a changeling for a full month

and their appearance in this episode wearing their old uniform suggests that the switch had occurred several episodes ago.

Do any of these episodes contain major hints or even subtle ones at this character’s true nature?

Comment: On that page, it says in the background information that Alexander Siddig (Bashir's actor) didn't know until that episode.  So I suppose you're asking about anything other than what the character did?

Comment: @Izkata Huh...I could've sworn I read through it all...I guess I didn't see that on the page.  I suppose then yes, I am looking for that.

Comment: @Izkata: That would have prevented the actor from intentionally including any subtle clues. However, it would not prevent the script writer (who may or may not have been in on the plan to have Bashir be a changeling) to have Bashir do or say things that may have seemed slightly off at the time, but would be spot-on in retrospect, knowing that we were watching changeling-Bashir.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I highly doubt there would have been any prior hints, as it would have tipped off the actor - who didn't know until the episode itself.  Buried in the [background information for *In Purgatory's Shadow*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/In_Purgatory%27s_Shadow_%28episode%29#Story_and_script) is this quote from him:

> - Of the Bashir as Changeling storyline, Alexander Siddig said "Apparently, I'd been a changeling for the previous three or four shows before this fact was revealed in "In Purgatory's Shadow". But I didn't know it until the last minute. So obviously it had no impact in how I'd played him in those earlier episodes. Once I did know, I had a chance to do something about how the other Bashir behaved. But what a shock!" *(Star Trek: Deep Space Nine Companion)*

Comment: Siddig was quite annoyed at that, incidentally. It was one of two times major events in his character's life were revealed to him only in the script. The other was when the writers decided to make him an Augment. I can understand their reasoning in this case, however; it plays into the 'anyone could be a Changeling' aspect quite nicely.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Siddig: *I never asked for this*.

Comment: So the next question is whether the writers knew when they were writing the previous episodes or was it a bit of an ass-pull they came up with when writing *In Purgoratory's Shadow*

Answer (score 10):

Well I didn't noticed any change. But I don't know Bashir as good as his best friend. In ["By Infernos Light"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/By_Inferno%27s_Light_%28episode%29) there is a dialog after Julian returned.

> **O'Brian:** "Four weeks? Are you telling me I've been hanging around a Changeling for over a month?"
>   **Bashir:** "And you even never suspected it wasn't me?"
>   **O'Brian:** "No! And the worst part is, the clues were right in front of me!"
>   **Bashir:** "What clues?"
>   **O'Brian:** "Well, for one thing, he was a lot easier to get along with."

O'Brian must know. The last four weeks he spent a lot more time with him than our four time 45 minutes. It might be banter, but I can imagine that the changeling actually was nicer - just to be on the safe side. He doesn't know the friendship between the both that pre
cisely.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone back and watched those episodes multiple times.  The Bashir changeling performs complicated surgery on Sisko in "Rapture", so he must have figured out how to actually be a doctor, which is very impressive.

About the best clue I can come up with is Bashir's initial encounter with Odo in "The Begotten".  Bashir looks clearly annoyed with Odo when he comes into the infirmary, which would be in keeping with the Changelings' attitude toward Odo at the time.

Comment: The script indicates that Bashir's off expression is a supressed smirk. Odo has  become quite the regular visitor *"INFIRMARY: BASHIR is working at his console when ODO walks in,  holding himself very stiffly. Bashir almost smiles at 
 the sight of him -- truth is, Odo's been coming in a  lot lately with all sorts of minor ailments."*